# Property in view missing after browser back

Tags: sapui5

I noticed that there seems to be a problem with some model bindings in one particular xml view of my application if i use the browser-back button or navigate back to the page.
I can see in the network tab that my model is still loaded fine and also that the property ('tlc' - a text for a src of an Image) is also there.

[image: Property is loaded]

But most of the time (not ALL of the time - also very strange) i get a 404 not found because it seems to be empty for mostly only ONE element of a List (which all are loading images the same way...):

[image]

It works fine when i open up the url with this view initially or when i refresh the page.

This is how my List with the Images is defined:

```
<List id="startListUpcoming" class="upcomingList sapUiSmallMarginTop" showNoData="false" items="{
  path: 'startlist>/startlistElements',
  filters: [
    {
      path: 'competitors/0/isMarked',
      operator: 'EQ',
      value1: false
    }
  ]
}">
  <items>
    <CustomListItem type="Active" press="onClickStarter">
      <HBox>
        <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
          <Image src="/img/flags/{startlist>competitors/0/athlete/nation/tlc}.png" error="onFlagError" width="50px" height="50px" />
          <Label text="{startlist>time}"/>
        </VBox>
        <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
          <Link text="{startlist>competitors/0/athlete/firstName} {startlist>startlist>competitors/0/athlete/familyName}" press="onClickRiderName"/>
            <Label text="{startlist>competitors/0/horse/name}"/>
        </VBox>
      </HBox>
    </CustomListItem>
  </items>
</List>
```

As i said. Most of the time only one element of this list is affected by this..
Anyone any idea why this might be the case? It's a really strange one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that i was setting the model on the view inside the `attachRequestCompleted` callback, which somehow led to the model being incomplete (not sure why):

I changed:

```
oJSONModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent) {
    this.getView().setModel(oJSONModel);
}
```

to:

```
oJSONModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent) {
}
this.getView().setModel(oJSONModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is caused by an incomplete implementation.

For example:

If Page1 calls the GetEntitySet where fields **A,B and C** are returned.

Then you navigate to Page2 where you call an Update or a GetEntity where *only* fields **A and C** are returned.

This causes the OData client cache to be updated with a blank value.

This might not be your issue. I have not checked the OData object like you when I got this issue.

Comment: I am using plain JSON as model and i am not calling `GetEntitySet`. Will still check if i can somehow debug the client cache. Thanks for the answer